# Joining JPA entities using calculated attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Please consider the following classes:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Entity1Identity id;

}
```

---

```
@Embeddable
public class Entity1Identity implements Serializable{
    private int col1;
    private String col2;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Entity2 {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "col1", referencedColumnName = "col1"),
        //I have to join "col2" here, and want to use the value from getCol2()
    })
    private Entity1 e;

    private String getCol2() {
        String someCalculatedAttribute;
        //(...)
        return someCalculatedAttribute;
    }
}
```

**How can I achieve the action stated on the `@JoinColumns` comment?**

I've tried `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas`, or simply using a `@Formula`, but I can reference `getCol2()` using those (can't use HQL / JPQL).

I don't want to create a separate repository method to make the join (that's what I'm currently using, and want to change).

I'm open to solutions that use hibernate/spring/some other proprietary methods.

Thank you!

Comment: Of course you can't reference `getCol2()`, did you expect to reference Java code from SQL? Why not simply store `calculatedAttribute` in a column?

Comment: Because we're talking about JPA/Hibernate we can indeed reference java attributes in JPQL/HQL. Unfortunately that is not available in the aforementioned annotations. Additionally, and unfortunately, I don't have control over the database schema.

Comment: Umm... no. Both JPQL and HQL get compiled to SQL first, and you cannot reference a Java method from SQL

Comment: When you do a query using something like `col = :value` you are indirectly referencing a java attribute through `:value`, determined at runtime. I'm just looking for a way to do exactly that without having to make a new repository method.

Comment: And I'm trying to tell you what you're asking is impossible